# How to click multiple 'Add to cart' button from product list using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am able to add single and all available items, but not sure how to add multiple items

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYZsx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGZqN.png)

Comment: Please provide more detail, what do you mean by multiple items? share the code that you have tried or the error that you're getting.

Comment: I need to add more then 1 item

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my code, I have searched for an item and three items were listed and added all three items to cart, Now I want to know how to add two items to cart using loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, please the next time provide more details and please just don't share the code with a screenshot.....

Anyway,

To click all the buttons:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='product-action']")))
for i in driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="[class='product-action']"):
    i.click()
```

To click just the first two buttons (again, not sure what you really want):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='product-action']")))
    for i in driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="[class='product-action']")[0:2]:
        i.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary element from items using methods items.remove(), items.pop(), del items[].